# Unknown column 'locals_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a recipe page where a user clicks a recipe link and the data(full recipe) is displayed on the following page, but I can't seem to get it to work.  When I try to run the page I get the error "Unknown column 'locals_id' in 'where clause." Here is my code so far.

```
?php 
    //connection variables
        $hostname = 'hostname';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = '********';
        $database = 'database';  

        //connect to the server
        $dbc = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to mySQL server");

        //connect to the database
        mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");


        $recipe_link = "-1";
        if (isset($_GET['locals_id'])) {
          $recipe_link = $_GET['locals_id'];
        }

        $query_recipeDetails = sprintf("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE locals_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($recipe_link, "int"));
        $result = mysql_query($query_recipeDetails, $dbc) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_recipeDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);



?>
```

I'm pretty new when it comes to php so I've really been tearing my hair out on this one.  I looked through some of the other problems that were similar to mine but those didn't seem to help either.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If mysql says that there is no such column - then ... there is no such column

Comment: Put your database scheme. There's a typo in your sql. Check your scheme.

Comment: And wow! You are putting directly values from GET variable!!!!

Comment: @itachi: where do you see "directly"?

Comment: My mistake. But it doesn't makes sense in casting the variable in sql statement rather than while assigning the variable. If its possible to put the logic outside the statement, it should be done as debugging sql error becomes easier.

Comment: So I think I went about doing this the wrong way.  locals_id ends up being the name of a specific recipe in the "title" column of recipe table.  when I print out locals_id it shows the recipe title correctly.  I guess I just don't know the right syntax to get the rest of the data for that specific recipe_id to display.  Am I going about this the wrong way, or is there perhaps an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Query and code seems correct.

Check your column name carefully. there might be some `typo` mistake or check for `case sensitivity`. `locals_id`  might be `local_id`

Comment: Column names are case insensitive in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Check the column name is similar to  "locals_id" in database tables and these are case sensitive, otherwise give column name between this symbol ` in the query.

eg.,

```
`locals_id`
```

Comment: Column names are case insensitive in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Run from mysql console:

SHOW CREATE TABLE recipe;

or run

SHOW FIELDS FROM recipe;

And you'll find out the correct names for the columns. Anyway MySQL column names are case insensitive, so you have a misstype in you script probably.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone! I figured it out. It was indeed something to do with locals_id not being a column name.  The correct name was recipe_id. I feel silly for not seeing it.